# Figures side by side: captions and size problems

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I'm quite new to Latex and I'm having some problems placing figures side by side. I want the first image to be shifted a bit on left side of the text as well as the second a little bit on the right, so that I can make them bigger without them overlapping. Moreover, I want sub-captions centered with respect to the graph.
So I would like to ask you:

- what is wrong in my code?
- Are there better ways to do what I want to do?
- How can I enlarge the space between text and images?

I attach what I was able to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.499\textwidth}%
\hspace{-2.5 cm}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{{example-image-a}}%
\subcaption{Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura}%
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.499\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{{example-image-a}}%
\subcaption{Quel ramo del lago di Como, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene non interrotte di monti}%
\hspace{-2.5 cm}%
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to have image wider than text width, `changepage` package can help you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-22mm}{-22mm}
\parbox{\linewidth}{% I don't know why is needed that caption has expected width
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\includegraphics{example-image-a}%
\subcaption{Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura}%
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\includegraphics{example-image-b}%
\subcaption{Quel ramo del lago di Como, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene non interrotte di monti}%
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption}
}% end of parbox
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it and it works well. however is it possible to add label to each figure (subfigure)? Because I have some problems

Comment: @user257608, each subfigure has a label: `(a)`, `(b)`! What you mean with *add a label*?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent overlap between the images, it's best to use the option `width=\linewidth` instead of the somewhat indirect `scale=0.4`. (And I'd set that width to `0.48\textwidth`, not `0.499\textwidth`...) With this adjustment in place, it's not necessary to employ `\hspace*` directives either.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Quel ramo del lago di Como, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene non interrotte di monti}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption} % overall caption
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico, I tried your code but for my purposes it works better solution by zarko. Anyway thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

A subfigure is just a minipage with captions.  Not sure why I need `\strut`s around `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace*{-2.5 cm}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth+2.5cm-0.5\columnsep}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{{example-image-a}}%
\caption{Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura}%
\end{subfigure}%
\strut\hfill\strut
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth+2.5cm-0.5\columnsep}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{{example-image-a}}%
\caption{Quel ramo del lago di Como, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene non interrotte di monti}%
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{-2.5 cm}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi John Kormylo, thank you for your answer. I will try as soon as possible your code!